# jquery: How can I trigger click() without editing the element state?

Tags: jquery

I need to trigger a click function assigned to a checkbox, but without actually changing it's checked state (which click() does).

Scenario:  I have a form with several checkboxes that when selected reveal a textarea.  This works fine, but I also need to call the click() function on $(document).ready()

My code is below, please note I have very limited access to changing the generated html. I have an object (admin_panels) which will store each checkbox and the texarea it should bring up.

```
var admin_panels = {"checkbox-id" : "textarea-id"};

$(document).ready(function(){
for (var elem in admin_panels) {
    $("#" + elem).click(admin_slide);
    // $("#" + elem).click();
}
})
function admin_slide() { 
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $("#" + admin_panels[this.id] + "-wrapper").slideDown();
  }else{
        $("#" + admin_panels[this.id] + "-wrapper").slideUp();
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to call the `admin_slide` function for an element, you can do this:

```
admin_slide.call(domElement);
```

The value of `this` within the `admin_slide` function will be set to `domElement`.

In this case, `domElement` could be `$('#'+elem)[0]` or `document.getElementById(elem)`.

**Edit**:

Another way to do this, using jQuery methods exclusively, is: `$(selector).each(admin_slide)`. So your code could be:

```
for (var elem in admin_panels) {
    $("#" + elem).click(admin_slide)
                 .each(admin_slide);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the checkboxes states from changing, include `event.preventDefault` in your event handler code.  That with interjay's answer will look like this:

```
$("#" + elem).click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    admin_slide.call(this);     
});
```

The only bad thing about this approach is that the checkbox's state is changed when admin_slide() is called, but gets changed back after that.  You can work around that easily enough by changing what happens in your admin_slide function.

```
function admin_slide() { 
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $("#" + admin_panels[this.id] + "-wrapper").slideUp();
    }else{
        $("#" + admin_panels[this.id] + "-wrapper").slideDown();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this keep the state from changing every time?

Answer (score -1):

So, you are assigning the click function in the document.ready? Why not just call admin_slide directly in addition to assigning the event handler?

Comment: This would be better as a comment, and because `admin_slide` relies on `this` being set to the proper element, which calling the function directly doesn't accomplish.